# simple input-output with time delay

Tags: c++

Let's say I have an input signal, could be a random double:

```
while(true){
  double t; // = current time, let's assume I know that
  double input = rand();
}
```

I want to generate an output signal that simply applies a 0.5 sec time delay (a 0.5sec dead time in signal processing terms.)

```
while(true){
  double input = rand();
  // in pseudocode double output(t) = input(t-0.5)
}
```

I was thinking about storing the input in a vector, along with a time stamp in another vector, and then look up output = input(0.5sec ago). However, that seems very inefficient.

What's an appropriate data structure for this type of problem? (A buffer that let's me recall a value that was stored 0.5 sec ago and discards recorded values that are further in the past than the chosen time delay)

Comment: How often and how fast does the input occur?

Comment: In input occurs continuously, every cycle in while(true)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The struct you use to store data should have a timestamp (either expiry or the moment it was enqueued) along with the double value.

The data structure to store the structs should be a priority queue (sorted on timestamp).

The consumer thread should sleep for n milliseconds where n is initialized to 500ms.

When the consumer pops the first item, it can check the second item and calculate n (the amount of time to sleep for the next iteration). Else it can sleep again for 500 ms.

Let me know if I should write code for it.

Comment: Apologies if I didn't describe the problem accurately, the input and output occur continuously, every cycle in the while look. I only want the output to lag by 0.5sec.

Answer (score 0):

What immediately comes to mind is the [Producer-Consumer Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem).

Have the producer push the input to a `std::queue` and every 0.5 seconds (using a `std::thread`) have the consumer pop from it.

Comment: Apologies if I didn't describe the problem accurately, the input and output occur continuously, every cycle in the while look. I only want the output to lag by 0.5sec